# How generate BUILD files for Python project

Tags: bazel

i would like to test Bazel for a current Python application (Flask). Do you know if it possible to manage BUILD files automatically ? Like the gazel tool for golang projects.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am not aware of an existing tool to generate BUILD files from Python sources.

If it can help, here is a blog post where the author migrated a Python project to Bazel: https://jayconrod.com/posts/97/migrating-to-bazel-part-1

Take a look at the [workspace rules](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/workspace.html) and [Python rules](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/python.html)